# Positioning buttons over background images

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a background image. I wanted to position a button below the login with Facebook and login with Twitter but it doesn't get positioned for all screen sizes. How do I go about doing that?

[image: Login screen]

Comment: You can  use AutoLayout or autoresizingmask to fix them for all screen sizes.

Comment: Try to use center constraints of autolayout. If you are sure that image is stretching properly across devices just set center vertically buttons and give fixed spaces between them.